# Default values lost with update products used the Mangeto API for a store view

Tags: api, magento, import, product, magento-1.5

I use the Magento-API to update a product. It works great, but I have one problem after the update for one store view: Only two fields in the update are stored (for example "description" and "name"), but all attributes have lost the flag "Use Default Value" in the store view! If I make later a full update for the default data, the attributes from the store view will not updated to the default values.

Does anyone know the problem with the Magento-API?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have it: you must set all attributes, which you don't want to update, to "false". in this case the product-model from magento take the default value from the product.

I don't know this works if you use the normal api via soap, because I use the api-model directly. but i think it works also in the normal way.

Answer (score 0):

It works via soap as well.

```
$client->call($sessionId, 'catalog_product.update', array($productId, array('visibility'=>false), $storeId));
```

This will set the visibility attribute of $product to "Use Default Values" for $storeId, but there isn't a way that I know of to preserver or look up if an attribute is "Using Default Value" before assuming it needs to be set. Does anyone know of a solution to check?